# JBox2D: простой пример создания мира

Tags: box2d, java

Может поделится кто простым примером создания мира в `jBox2d`? с несколькими разными объектами (треугольник, круг, не правильный многоугольник), нашел с коробками, но там они все в один массив пихаются и как с ними работать по отдельности не очень ясно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте [@madsmilexd](/users/13979/madsmilexd)

не уверен что именно то что нужно. но там по игровым движкам было несколько семплов

[DevAppsDirect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inappsquared.devappsdirect&hl=ru)

да и вообще  там много всего интересного))

Comment: не совсем то что хотел) и там как я понял ориентированно под мобильные ОС) 
хотя думаю это мне пригодится тоже)
спасибо!)